# Column title repeating in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to export some posts based on custom meta data. I cannot export the ID of the post because I will run into a duplicate key problem when I import the data into a different database.

When I run the SQL query to select which fields, I am excluding the ID:

```
SELECT 'post_author', 
       'post_date', 
       'post_content', 
       'post_title', 
       'post_excerpt', 
       'post_status', 
       'comment_status', 
       'ping_status', 
       'post_password', 
       'post_name', 
       'post_modified', 
       'post_content_filtered', 
       'post_parent', 
       'guid', 
       'post_type', 
       'post_mime_type', 
       'comment_count' 
FROM   wp_posts 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
         ON wp_postmeta.post_ID = wp_posts.ID 
WHERE  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'InternalOnly' 
         AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL );
```

I get the column title as each entry in the column: http://screencast.com/t/A8ySD6frl6Z

So essentially I need to reference the ID of the post when I run the query but I can't include the ID in the output. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: why are you using single quotes? put your column_titles in between `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting string literals, not fields. Take out the single quotes and you should be good (assuming that the query is correct)

```
SELECT post_author, post_date, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, post_modified, post_content_filtered, post_parent, guid, post_type, post_mime_type, comment_count FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_ID = wp_posts.ID WHERE ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'InternalOnly' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove quotes: `SELECT post_author, ...`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're quoting each column name. What you're asking it to do in that case is to select the literal string "post_author", "post_date", etc., rather than asking it to select the data from those columns. Correct it to "SELECT post_author, post_date..."